# Concatenate date variable mdx

Tags: sql-server, mdx

Hello guys sorry to bother again with a horrible question

I have the following mdx and I need to format the date YYYYMMDD but I am having trouble as no matter how I phrase it it wont compile on the store procedure, or if it does the resulting mdx is no good.

Heres the code I have so far, using sqlserver 2000.

```
set @CONSULTA = 'select [' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @fecha, 112)+ '] AS [' +YYYYMMDD+ '], A.* 
    from (SELECT
    isnull(CAST("[Measures].[Cajas Dia]" As float(18,6)),2) As cajas_dia,
    isnull(CAST("[Measures].[P Redondeadas]" As int),2) As pz_redondeo
          FROM openrowset(''MSOLAP'',''DATASOURCE=XXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXX; User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;'', '+ '''' + @MDX +''''+')) as A
```

'

Comment: Does enclosing CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @fecha, 122) in brackets is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use style 112 instead of 122 on the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Also not sure why you have square brackets around that in your query.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @fecha, 112)
```

Comment: Silly me been ages since I concatenate anything, and I really couldnt recall the '''

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

There is no style 122 and I assume you are trying to bring the date back as a literal and alias that column as `YYYYMMDD`?

```
set @CONSULTA = 'select ''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @fecha, 112)+ ''' AS [YYYYMMDD], A.* 
    from (SELECT
    isnull(CAST("[Measures].[Cajas Dia]" As float(18,6)),2) As cajas_dia,
    isnull(CAST("[Measures].[P Redondeadas]" As int),2) As pz_redondeo
          FROM openrowset(''MSOLAP'',''DATASOURCE=XXXX; Initial Catalog=OLAP_HDZ; User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;'', '+ '''' + @MDX +''''+')) as A'
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake about the style you are right about style 112, and no I need the date with that format like 20101203

Comment: @Enrique - er, What? I never said you didn't.

Comment: sorry no mean to be disrespectful, I mean I need the date with that format, but as it stand its given me just a alias and not the date format.

Comment: @Enrique - In the generated SQL it will generate something like `select '20101203' AS [YYYYMMDD],..` is that not what you need? If not can you update your question with an example of the desired result so we can tell you what you need to do to get there.